# Are these array initialization methods in Fortran equally fast?

Tags: performance, fortran

In Fortran you can initialize whole array just by typing

```
array = 1.0
```

But it is also possible to type

```
do i = first_element:last_element
  array(i) = 1.0
enddo
```

Is the first method faster or is there no performance difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any sensible contemporary Fortran compiler would *optimise* the loop to the same assembly as the short-form initialisation.

(Optimising Fortran compilers have been around since the 1960s).

If you are in any doubt of this, check that generated assembly.